# Intervention Image NotReadableException bizzare

Tags: php, laravel, gd, intervention

I'm writing an image upload form with Laravel 4.2 and Intervention Image package.

Some of uploaded photos are causing an error 'NotReadableException' and some arent.

Here is my code:

```
$img = Image::make(public_path('/upload/tmp/'.$name));
$img->backup();
$watermark = Image::make(public_path('/img-icons/watermark.gif'));
$img->insert($watermark, 'bottom-right', 10, 10);
$img->save(public_path('/upload/tmp/normal-'.$name));
$img->reset();
$img->fit(175, 140);
$img->save(public_path('/upload/tmp/min-'.$name));
$img->reset();
$img->fit(496, 502);
$img->save(public_path('/upload/tmp/main-'.$name));
```

File is uploaded into desired directory, and it is accessable.

I checked dirs and files permissions - both correct.

I check php values (memory_limit 384MB, post_max_size 64MB, upload_max_filesize 64MB).

GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible), Intervention Image version: 2.3.8

I'm out of ideas - some photos (made with the same camera) are cousing this error, and some of them arent.

I'll be glad for any help.

Comment: Do you have FileInfo extension enable? You need to have `extension=php_fileinfo.dll` enabled in your php.ini

Comment: Yes, I have fileinfo enabled on my server.

Comment: Could be that their format is invalid. Try opening the images which throw the exception in Photoshop. If they don't open then you know what your issue is